# Bypass Dex in KubeFlow for accessing a seldon model via curl

Tags: curl, kubeflow, seldon, seldon-core

I followed the example at: https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/tree/master/examples/kubeflow

## Steps Done:

1. kubectl port-forward $(kubectl get pods -l istio=ingressgateway -n istio-system -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') -n istio-system 8005:80
2. kubectl create namespace kubeflow-user-example-com
3. kubectl config set-context $(kubectl config current-context) --namespace=kubeflow-user-example-com
4. Create a language wrapper for the seldon model
5. Uploaded it to the docker registry

I would like to curl my SeldonDeployment in Kubeflow:

```
apiVersion: machinelearning.seldon.io/v1
kind: SeldonDeployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: seldon
  name: seldon-sentiment
  namespace: kubeflow-user-example-com
spec:
  annotations:
    project_name: NLP Pipeline
    deployment_version: v1
  name: seldon-sentiment
  predictors:
    - componentSpecs:
        - spec:
            containers:
              - image: 'localhost:5000/seldon-sentiment:0.1'
                imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
                name: sentiment
                resources:
                  requests:
                    memory: 1Mi
            terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 20
      graph:
        children: []
        endpoint:
          type: REST
        name: sentiment
        type: MODEL
      name: sentiment
      replicas: 1
      annotations:
        predictor_version: v1
```

When I try to query the deployment via curl, I am redirected to Dex.

```
curl -k -O http://localhost:8005/seldon/kubeflow-user-example-com/seldon-sentiment-sentiment-0-sentiment/api/v0.1/predictions -d "{'data': { 'ndarray': ['Hello world this is a test']}}" -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

*   Trying ::1:8005...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8005 (#0)
> POST /seldon-sentiment-sentiment-0-sentiment/api/v0.1/predictions HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8005
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 54
>
* upload completely sent off: 54 out of 54 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< location: /dex/auth?client_id=kubeflow-oidc-authservice&redirect_uri=%2Flogin%2Foidc&response_type=code&scope=profile+email+groups+openid&state=MTY2NTk2MTY
< date: Sun, 16 Oct 2022 23:07:52 GMT
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 2
< server: istio-envoy
< content-length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: I removed the `dex` tag as this question is not related to Android dex files. Please read at least the tag quick help before using it.

Comment: Are we talking about the same dex?Dex is an identity service that uses OpenID Connect to drive authentication for other apps.

Comment: No and that is the problem The dex tag is for Android dex code only. I am not sure what tag to use for the Dex identity service (if one exists yet).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to give an authentication token if you want to curl the API. This can be done by fetching the token generated in the cookie. Dex has python codes to fetch the token and then you can curl the URL with the retrieved token in the headers.